# Making a component for Joomla to let users subscribe to specific Dropbox folders with limited rights

Tags: php, api, joomla, dropbox

I´m investigating the possiblities of making a dropbox component for Joomla for the following application:

1. The siteowner has a forum (kunena-based) with different categories.
2. For each category there must be a specific dropbox folder.
3. All registered Joomla-users must be able to "subscribe" to each dropbox folder within the forum.
4. Once a user is subscribed he/she has access to that folder in dropbox but he/she must only be allowed to upload and download, not to delete files.
5. Only the Dropbox-folder author (siteowner) must be able to delete files.

Does the dropbox API allow for this kind of scenario to be achieved with PHP script or is Dropbox limited to only allow standard "share folder" functionalities?

Answer (score 0):

Dropbox has no permission model like this (read/write but not delete). There's also no access via the API to share folders, so I don't see how you would do this.